# MongoDB MapReduce Standard Deviation over date range

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Good Afternoon SO, I wonder if anybody could help me.  I am currently investigating using MongoDB Aggregation Framework and MapReduce functions.

My dataset looks like this

```
[{
     "Name" : "Person 1",
    "RunningSpeed" : [{
            "Date" : ISODate("2005-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 10
        }, {
            "Date" : ISODate("2006-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 20
        }, {
            "Date" : ISODate("2007-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 30
        }, {
            "Date" : ISODate("2008-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 40
        }

    ]

}, {
    "Name" : "Person 2",
    "RunningSpeed" : [{
            "Date" : ISODate("2005-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 5
        }, {
            "Date" : ISODate("2006-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 10
        }, {
            "Date" : ISODate("2007-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 20
        }, {
            "Date" : ISODate("2008-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 40
        }

    ]

}, {
    "Name" : "Person 3",
    "RunningSpeed" : [{
            "Date" : ISODate("2005-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 20
        }, {
            "Date" : ISODate("2006-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 10
        }, {
            "Date" : ISODate("2007-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 30
        }, {
            "Date" : ISODate("2008-07-23T23:00:00.000Z"),
            "Value" : 25
        }

    ]

}
```

]

I have done a lot of research and as I an see there is no out of the box support for doing SD calculations. I have reviewed a few links and SO posts and came up with this URL https://gist.github.com/RedBeard0531/1886960, which seems to be what I am looking for.

So enough about the background what I would like to do is generate a chart of SDs over each year.

The current function does not take inconsideration each year only the value as a whole.  I have changed the map function to and have no idea where to put the group date function.

```
function map() {
    emit(1, // Or put a GROUP BY key here
     {sum: this.RunningSpeed.value, // the field you want stats for
      min: this.RunningSpeed.value,
      max: this.RunningSpeed.value,
      count:1,
      diff: 0, // M2,n:  sum((val-mean)^2)
});
```

}

However I just get zero's.  Could anybody help me adapt this function?

Comment: If you want to group on year you need the `emit` key (the 1 with the comment about GROUP BY next to it) to be the year or something like that that will group the results by year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use getFullYear() and a forEach loop through each RunningSpeed entry:

```
function map() {
   this.RunningSpeed.forEach(function(data){
      var year = data.Date.getFullYear();
      emit(year, // Or put a GROUP BY key here, the group by key is Date.getFullYear()
          {sum: data.Value, // the field you want stats for
           min: data.Value,
           max: data.Value,
           count: 1,
           diff: 0, // M2,n: sum((val-mean)^2)
          });
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the for loop is what i was missing